# Call Sharepoint from Office 365 app

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I'm just doing some very basic reading around the new Office 365 dev model. Would it be posible in an Outlook app that sits in a task pane to add an item to a list in your Office 365 Sharepoint teamsite.

Answer (score 1):

Mail apps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135(v=office.15).aspx) are just small HTML/JavaScript pages that load inside Outlook or Outlook Web App. You should be able to programmatically add things to SharePoint, though you may need to do that work in a Web API that your mail app invokes. I published a sample mail app that does something similar: saving attachments to the user's OneDrive. All of the attachment retrieval and saving happens in a Web API. https://github.com/jasonjoh/attachments-demo